# Entity Framework Core (6.0.20) migrations not adding primary key to DB

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have a Entity Framework Core 6.0.20 that I use in a code first manner to manage the DB schema of my application.

For some reason, all of my `[Key]` data annotations are being ignored. It is happening to all of my entities.

Here is a sample of one of the entities.

```
public class JobCollectionRoute
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(max)")]
    public string? fullRouteJson { get; set; }
}
```

All of my entities have a primary key but when I do the add-migration xxxyyyzzz, the `migrationBuilder.AddPrimaryKey` code is not being generated. All of the columns, data types, etc are generated just fine. Also, some of the foreign key constraints are being generated, but the update-database fails with a message like this.

> There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'JobCollectionRoute' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK_JobCollection_JobCollectionRoute_JobCollectionRouteID'.
> Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors

In the DB, there is no indication of a primary key being applied.

Here is one of the migration examples. My `ID` column should have a primary key constraint as it has the `[Key]` annotation.

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.AddColumn<Guid>(
            name: "JobCollectionRouteID",
            table: "JobCollection",
            type: "uniqueidentifier",
            nullable: true);

    migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_JobCollection_JobCollectionRouteID",
            table: "JobCollection",
            column: "JobCollectionRouteID");

    migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
            name: "FK_JobCollection_JobCollectionRoute_JobCollectionRouteID",
            table: "JobCollection",
            column: "JobCollectionRouteID",
            principalTable: "JobCollectionRoute",
            principalColumn: "ID");
}
```

Again, this is happening on all my tables. Any thoughts on what is going on and where I can look to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the configured relationship between JobCollection and JobCollectionRoute? The configuration of these may cause an issue with attempting to define the PK if it is set up as a one-to-one or possibly an owned relationship.

Comment: The thing is, migration code that you have shown is *adding the column* that you want to become a PK. But it is *not creating the table*. Which means it has been created by another migration, and should have another PK (EFC do not support tables w/o PK). With that in mind, it would be good to provide reproducible example, e.g. initial entity and the modification which lead to the problematic migration in question.

Comment: @marc_s That's true for the column types. But `DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)` attribute is misleading, it is just the attribute (data annotation) way to say that the value is auto-generated. No more, no less. For int type it implies `IDENTITY` column type, but not always (for instance it could be sequence, HiLo or even client side generated pure `INT` db column). So the reason is not obvious at all, and needs more details (see my previous comment).

Comment: Have you included the JobCollectionRoute class in DbContext (DbSet<JobCollectionRoute>)? If so I also recommend using the Fluent API to configure the primary key for the JobCollectionRoute. modelBuilder.Entity<JobCollectionRoute>().HasKey(e => e.ID);

Comment: Oops, sorry, the migration shown is for creating FK in another table referencing the PK of the table in question. So, how do you know the `ID` is not a PK in the "JobCollection**Route**" table? Do you have a fluent API calls which change PKs? Really need [mre], otherwise I'm afraid the question will be closed.